# Apache NiFi For Importing Data From RDMBS to HDFS - Performance Comparison with SQOOP

Tags: apache-nifi

We are exploring Apache NiFi as a general purpose data ingestion tool for our enterprise requirements.

One typical data ingestion requirement is moving data from RDBMS
systems to HDFS.

I was able to build RDBMS to HDFS data movement flow in NiFi using GenerateTableFetch and ExecuteSQL Processors provided by NiFi and everything worked fine for smaller tables.

[image]

But, I couldn't test the flow for bigger tables as I was using a standalone distribution.

Has anyone done a performance comparison of NiFi with SQOOP for similar requirements ?

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteSQL` and `ExecuteSQLRecord` are a better choice. The former will just automatically convert result sets into an Avro sequence. The latter gives you more freedom on how you write the output (JSON, CSV, etc.). One nice thing about `ExecuteSQL` is that you can chain it with `MergeRecord` to combine multiple modest-sized result pages into a much bigger block of data, and `MergeRecord` can use the `ParquetWriter` to give you ready-made Parquet for insertion into HDFS.