# Apache NiFi - "ExecuteSQL" runs the Query in Parallel?

Tags: apache-nifi

Apache NiFi provides "ExecuteSQL" processor to execute a query and return the results as flow files. But, if we choose the Execution option as "All Nodes" , does 
NiFi divides the query in to different batches and executes each of them in parallel (similar to how SQOOP does) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use ExecuteSQL and select all nodes, then the same query is run on all nodes.

If you want sqoop like behavior you will want to use processors like GenerateTableFetch on primary node only, then use a load-balanced connection connected to ExecuteSQL so that the fetch queries get distributed across the cluster.

Comment: Bryan, would you be able to answer this question also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126682/apache-nifi-for-importing-data-from-rdmbs-to-hdfs-performance-comparison-with

Comment: Hard to answer since it depends on lots of factors.. size of DB table, size of NiFi cluster, hardware specs of cluster, etc. In general, sqoop will probably win for large scale performance.

Comment: The GenerateTableFetch will generate multiple queries based on the size of the table and pass it to subsequent processors as flow files, ExecuteSQL in this case. How can I load balance the ExecuteSQL processor ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: I mentioned this in the answer, you run GenerateTableFetch on primary node, connect it to ExecuteSQL, and configure load balancing on the connection - https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/load-balancing-across-the-cluster

Comment: Bryan, does the Execution option of ExecuteSQL should be selected as "All Nodes" for load balanced connection to work properly. I am trying NiFi my local machine, so no way to test it to make sure how it's working.

Comment: yes the only processors that should ever be set to 'primary node only' are source processors, so in this case that would be GenerateTableFetch. Also, you can easily run a two node cluster locally to test it out.

Comment: Let's say if my source processor is a kafka consumer, which option should I choose ? Does choosing the "All Nodes" option make the read happens in parallel from multiple partitions ?

Comment: For Kafka you choose all nodes because the Kafka client knows how to create a consumer group and consume different messages on each node.

Comment: @BryanBende then what is the purpose of All nodes in Execution ? If the execution is always going to be in primary node ? What cases All Nodes is Better than primary node

Comment: Most of the time everything is set to 'All Nodes', you only use 'Primary Node Only' when there is an operation you only want to do once for a source processor